# Confidence intervals based on asymptotic normality

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation, maximum-likelihood, matrix, fisher-information

I wrote a report about `confidence intervals based on asymptotic normality`. However, my supervisor said that the definition in the second paragraph is wrong, but I do not know what is wrong. I have attached the report here. Can you please take a look and let me know what is wrong?

[image]

Comment: Looks kinda OK to me. I might be missing something very obvious though.

Comment: Apart from the description of the Hessian, I cannot find any definitions of anything in or near the second paragraph. Exactly what definition are you referring to?

Comment: I am referring this :"That is why the approximate information matrix is used. This is calculated by the negative of the expected value of the Hessian matrix"